# success function doesn't work using validation engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't make the script work, it's always returning errors when I run it

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#form1").validationEngine({
        ajaxSubmit: true,
        ajaxSubmitFile: "note/note.php",
        success: false
    });
    if (success == "true")
    {
        function()
        {
            window.alert("Report Sent!");
            //write a confirmation to the user
            document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Report Sent!";
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="";
            },3000);
        }
    }
});
```

what could be a good solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#form1").validationEngine({
        ajaxSubmit: true,
        ajaxSubmitFile: "note/note.php",
        success: false
    });
```

You're passing an object literal to the `validationEngine` method, the `success` property should be a function, that contains the code you want to see executed when the validation was successful, instead, you're setting it to false, and then go on like so:

```
if (success == "true")
{
     function()
     {
```

Not only are you using a variable that is actually an object property (and so you're creating a global variable, which is **EVIL**), you're declaring the function, but not invoking it. I've noticed you're checking the value of `success`, expecting it to be a string. The return value of your php script will be passed to the success callback function as an argument. I've taken the liberty of changing the function to reflect that,too:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#form1").validationEngine({
        ajaxSubmit: true,
        ajaxSubmitFile: "note/note.php",
        success: function(response)//response is what the php script returns
        {
            //the function from your if branch goes here
        }
    });
```

And you should be all right. The full code should look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{//notice the curly braces around what you're passing to validationEngine
    $("#form1").validationEngine({
        ajaxSubmit: true,
        ajaxSubmitFile: "note/note.php",
        success: function(response)
        {
            if (response !== 'true')
            {
                if (window.console)
                {
                    console.log(response);
                    alert('check your console to see the response');
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(response);
                }
                return;
            }
            alert("Report Sent!");//no need for window here
            document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Report Sent!";
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="";
            },3000);
        }
    });
    //As I said, you're passing an object, so you could write the code above like so:
    var validationArgs = {ajaxSubmit:true,ajaxSubmitFile:'note/note.php'};
    validationArgs.success = function()
    {
        //your function
    };
    $('#form1').validationEngine(validationArgs);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a callback function for this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var update = $("#update");
    // Callback 
    var onSuccess = function() {
        alert("Report Sent!");

        //write a confirmation to the user           
        update.html("Report Sent!");

        setTimeout(function(){
             update.html("");
        },3000);
    };

    $("#form1").validationEngine({
        ajaxSubmit: true,
        ajaxSubmitFile: "note/note.php",
        success: onSuccess
   });
});
```

Comment: This isn't all too good of an approach... your callback relies on the `update` variable to remain unchanged, if that gets reassigned along the way, I wish you the best of luck debugging... in your example, there's little difference between `update` and an implied global, really

Comment: No, the update variable is not a global variable. It is just available in the anonymous function in ($(document).ready). There is no reason to call the "var update = $('#update');" every time the callback method is called. Its a way to keep the code dry. http://rmurphey.com/blog/2010/07/12/patterns-for-dry-er-javascript/

Comment: I know it's not a global, but it's accessible all through the _"main jQuery scope"_, so it's _almost_ as bad as a global, try: `var onSuccess = (function(update){ return function(){update.html('');};}($('#update'));`. That creates a closure, and sets `update` as a variable that can only be referenced from within the `onSuccess` function. It only uses the selector once, and is much safer

Comment: But all code should not go in the "main jQuery scope" :) I think that your "Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IFFE)" only adds complexity. Anyway, good luck with your JS-coding and I hope that you got your original question answered.